# Add email templates to dropdown menu

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6

. I try :

```
    <template>
        <email>
            <simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate translate="label" module="simpleaffiliate">
                <label>Test Send Email</label>
                <file>test_sendemail.html</file>
                <type>html</type>   
            </simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate>

            <simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate translate="label" module="simpleaffiliate">
                <label>Test Send Email2</label>
                <file>test_sendemail2.html</file>
                <type>html</type>   
            </simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate>
        </email>
    </template>
```

and in system.xml

```
                    <emailtemplate translate="label">
                        <label>Email Template sent to new registered </label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment></comment>
                    </emailtemplate>
```

but I get only a option  :  Test Sent Email 2 (Default from Locale) , I want add other options . Can you help me :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the node `simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate` needs to be unique so it only knows about the last entry in the xml.

To make this work for more than one email you would need to make a change to the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Email_Template::toOptionArray` so when it loads from the xml it can work with more than one entry.

Or create your own source model for this case that will load all the email templates from the database and then adds in your new ones from the xml.